# AMR-NB support in javacv -> ffmpeg

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, javacv

I am trying to use AMR_NB Codec in JavaCV Android but having problems:

This is the code i run:

```
avcodec.avcodec_register_all();
avformat.av_register_all();
AVCodec mCodec = avcodec.avcodec_find_encoder(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_AMR_NB);
```

Output: The mCodec is null but if I pass avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_AAC than mCodec is not null

I am assuming that I have to recompile ffmpeg with --enable-libopencore-amrnb. So, I downloaded Android NDKr9+ffmpeg-2.0.2+last_stable_x264 and added them to javacv-cppjars folder, I have also installed opencore-amr library in /usr/local. In ffmpeg-2.0.2-android-arm.patch i added the --enable-libopencore-amrnb flag and run following command in terminal

```
ANDROID_NDK=/Users/android-ndk-r9b/ FFMPEG_VERSION=2.0.2 ./build_ffmpeg-android-arm.sh
```

The script runs but the libs are not generated and the jar is empty but if I remove the --enable-libopencore-amrnb flag back then the libs are generated successfully, Please advise what am I doing wrong? What should I do? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

by the way, I am using mac-osx

Thanks.

Comment: fyi: in the JavaCV script, disable-gpl and libx264 in your script. else you will be violating GPL.

Comment: Thanks @Edison I am aware of that, This project is just for learning purposes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that build_ffmpeg-android-arm.sh is [this](https://github.com/meebert/FotoShawp--/blob/master/javacv-cppjars/build_ffmpeg-android-arm.sh), if this is the case, to properly use --enable-libopencore-amrnb you also need to provide opencore-amr libraries (opencore source is not included in ffmpeg code), otherwise `configure` would complain about no opencore library found.

In order to fix it you would need to:

1. Download opencore-amr source code from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencore-amr/files/opencore-amr/opencore-amr-0.1.3.tar.gz/download) and copy it to javacv-cppjars folder.
2. Modify build_ffmpeg-android-arm.sh to build and link with opencore's libraries:

---

```
ANDROID_BIN=$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/    
ANDROID_ROOT=$ANDROID_NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/
tar -xjvf ffmpeg-$FFMPEG_VERSION.tar.bz2
mv ffmpeg-$FFMPEG_VERSION ffmpeg-$FFMPEG_VERSION-android-arm
cd ffmpeg-$FFMPEG_VERSION-android-arm
tar -xjvf ../last_stable_x264.tar.bz2
X264=`echo x264-snapshot-*`
cd $X264
./configure --enable-static --enable-pic --disable-cli --cross-prefix=$ANDROID_BIN/arm-linux-androideabi- --sysroot=$ANDROID_ROOT --host=arm-linux --extra-cflags="-DANDROID -fPIC -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mfpu=neon -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300" --extra-ldflags="-nostdlib -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -lgcc -ldl -lz -lm -lc"
make -j4
cd ../

tar -xzf ../opencore-amr-0.1.3.tar.gz
cd opencore-amr-0.1.3
BUILD_FLAGS="--sysroot=$ANDROID_NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-arm"
CFLAGS="$BUILD_FLAGS" CXXFLAGS="$BUILD_FLAGS" CPPFLAGS="$BUILD_FLAGS" RANLIB=$ANDROID_BIN/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib CC=$ANDROID_BIN/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc CXX=$ANDROID_BIN/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ LD=$ANDROID_BIN/arm-linux-androideabi-ld CPP=$ANDROID_BIN/arm-linux-androideabi-cpp LDFLAGS="-L$ANDROID_NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/lib/" ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnu --disable-shared
make
mv amrnb opencore-amrnb
cd ../

patch -p1 < ../ffmpeg-$FFMPEG_VERSION-android-arm.patch
./configure --prefix=$HOME/android --enable-libopencore-amrnb --extra-cflags="-Iopencore-amr-0.1.3" --extra-ldflags="-Lopencore-amr-0.1.3/opencore-amrnb/.libs" --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --disable-outdev=sdl --enable-libx264 --extra-cflags="-I$X264" --extra-ldflags="-L$X264" --enable-cross-compile --cc=$ANDROID_BIN/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=$ANDROID_ROOT --target-os=linux --arch=arm --extra-cflags="-DANDROID -fPIC -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mfpu=neon -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300" --extra-ldflags="-nostdlib -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8" --extra-libs="-lgcc -ldl -lz -lm -lc" --disable-stripping --disable-symver --disable-programs
make
LIBS="libavcodec/libavcodec.so libavdevice/libavdevice.so libavfilter/libavfilter.so libavformat/libavformat.so libavutil/libavutil.so libpostproc/libpostproc.so libswresample/libswresample.so libswscale/libswscale.so"
$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip $LIBS
mkdir -p com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/
cp $LIBS com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/
jar cvf ../ffmpeg-$FFMPEG_VERSION-android-arm.jar com/
rm -Rf com/
cd ../
```

---

And build again. Please note new section for building opencore is based on verson 0.1.3 and the small trick renaming `amrnb` folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am having an issue while compiling open core-amrnb here is the [script file](http://txt.do/1adq) and here is the [console output](http://txt.do/1adc), as you can see that libopencore-amrnb.a has no contents, Please help! by the way I am on OSX does that changes anything ?

Comment: @cyberpawn If you're running OSX, you would also need to point ranlib to android ranlib: RANLIB=$ANDROID_BIN/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib (Mac and Android ranlibs are not compatible). I edited the answer adding this (it may help someone else)

Comment: @cyberpawn You're welcome! I'm glad it helped. Please, keep in mind, that both h264 and AMR have royalties that you would need to re-check depending on your application final usage.